# help determining $a,b$ such that limit will exist and calculating it

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

So i have a limit: 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{ax}+b\ln(2-x)-1}{x-\sin{x}}$$

And i need to determine values for $a,b$ so that the limit will exist, and calculate the limit then.
There is also a $hint$, that i need to use Taylor series for this, so it might be helpful, but i don't know if i should look for the whole function or just a part of fraction.
Any help would really be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} {x-\sin{x}} = 0$$

In order to make the limit exist, the numerator of fraction $\frac{e^{ax}+b\ln(2-x)-1}{x-\sin{x}}$ must be zero so that the limit will become undefined form.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} e^{ax}+b\ln(2-x)-1 = 1+ b \ln(2) -1=0$$
Then use L'hosptial rule, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{ax}-1}{x-\sin{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{ae^{ax}}{1-\cos{x}}$$

To make the limit exist, in the same way, $\lim_{x \to 0} ae^{ax} = a = 0$

After L'hosptial twice, the answer should be $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{ax}+b\ln(2-x)-1}{x-\sin{x}} = 0$ and $a=b= 0$

Comment: As far as i know the limit can exist as well if it's not $\frac{0}{0}$, so i am not sure if this was using all of the possibilites?

Comment: @MathIsTheWayOfLife Yup it use up all of the possibilities because the initial condition is that the denominator of fraction $\frac{e^{ax}+b\ln(2-x)-1}{x-\sin{x}}$ is zero so the numerator must be zero otherwise the limit form $\frac{1}{0}$ or $\frac{-1}{0}$   does not converge over R.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested use [Series Expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html),

$$e^{ax}=1+\dfrac{ax}{1!}+\dfrac{(ax)^2}{2!}++\dfrac{(ax)^3}{3!}+\cdots$$

$$\ln(2-x)=\ln2+\ln\left(1-\dfrac x2\right)=\ln2-\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{(x/2)^r}r$$

$$\sin x=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$$

Answer (score 1):

It is sure that Taylor series help a lot. Let us try
$$e^{ax}=1+a x+\frac{a^2 x^2}{2}+\frac{a^3 x^3}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ $$\log(x-2)=\log (2)-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}-\frac{x^3}{24}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ $$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Replacing $$\frac{e^{ax}+b\ln(2-x)-1}{x-\sin{x}}=\frac{b \log (2)+x \left(a-\frac{b}{2}\right)+x^2
   \left(\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{b}{8}\right)+x^3
   \left(\frac{a^3}{6}-\frac{b}{24}\right)+O\left(x^4\right)}{\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)}$$ In order the limit exists, the constant term and the coefficients of the first and second powers of $x$ in numerator must be $0$. Then $???$

Comment: with that i just get a system of two equations with two variables right?

Comment: @MathIsTheWayOfLife. A bit more, I guess.